# Log4j2 AsyncLogger is always thread wait state

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I have created a simple Application with the below log configuration

```
      <appenders>
         <RollingRandomAccessFile  name="SUMMARY_ALL" fileName="./logs/summary.log" 
        filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/summary-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %p %c %L - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6"
                modulate="true" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
       </appenders>
```

Loggers as :

```
  <loggers>
    <root level="DEBUG" includeLocation="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="SUMMARY_ALL" />
    </root>
</loggers>
```

When I run this I always get the AsyncLogger in wait state. Can anyone please help. Attached is the snapshot of the ThreadDump

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was also posted to the log4j mailing list. Summary of the discussion:

The AsyncLogger thread will be in the waiting state most of the time, either waiting for new work to arrive, or waiting for the blocking I/O call to return.

This is expected behaviour. As long as events are correctly being logged this is not a problem.

Details on the difference between AsyncAppenders and AsyncLoggers can be found in Christian Grobmeier's blog post http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/log4j-2-performance-close-to-insane.html.